# Javascript tabs synchronization and server events

Tags: javascript, events, synchronization, dom-events, web-frontend

I need some help for my application and sorry for my English.

I'm working on front-end of a website. The final app should work fine with a lot of tabs (*~100 in a single browser*). Each tab needs to listen for a series of events sent from server and change its content dynamically.

I implemented this feature by using Websocket. Since opening a connection is very expensive. So I assigned a master tab, which will listen to events from the server and distribute them to other tabs using BroadcastChannel. And I have following questions：

---

> How to pick a master tab from all of them and make other tabs listen
>   to it?

I had these ideas:

### 1. Using BroadcastChannel.

During initilization tab asks using BroadcastChannel: "is there a master tab?". If it receives an answer, then it will continue working. If it won't receive any response, then it makes itself a master tab.

**Problem:**

If master tab will freeze inside of heavy loop, then it won't be able to respond in short amount of time, resulting 2 opened connections to the server and a conflict, which needs to be resolved.

### 2. Using LocalStorage.

During initilization tab will request some field called "`X`" *or smth*. If field is empty, then tab will create that field and assign some value, after it will make itself a master tab. If field "`X`" is not empty, then tab will make itself a slave tab.

**Problem:**

If two tabs will initilize in the same time, there might be a conflict:

```
tab_Alpha -> localStorage.getItem("haveMaster") -> undefined // There is no master, so i will make myself a master tab!
tab_Beta  -> localStorage.getItem("haveMaster") -> undefined // There is no master, so i will make myself a master tab!

tab_Alpha -> localStorage.setItem("haveMaster", true) // Now it's time to open connection and listen for events
tab_Beta  -> localStorage.setItem("haveMaster", true) // Now it's time to open connection and listen for events
```

And as a result, I have a conflict and two opened connections.

---

Can someone point out a lightweight solution to me? I will appreciate that.

---

**After a research.**

Halcyon suggested to use code from `gist.github.com/neilj/4146038`. But i was not satisfied with this solution, because if `Math.random()` will return 2 same numbers for 2 different tabs, while they will initilize, then browser will call `masterDidChange()` two times. And browser will end up, with conflict and 2 connections.

Then Dimitry Boger suggested to read this: `alpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage`.
I liked this solution more, but i still have managed to find a way to break it.
If each tab will freeze in couple of places, then it will result, again, an execution of `criticalSection()`.

Then i found a `wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm`. I have not found a method to break this locking mechanism, but there is a problem.
For this algorithm to work browser have to know exact amount of tabs before execution. Because if it will initilize a new tab, then previous one's can just miss this event and start their `criticalSection()` before the new tab will finish it's own.

So, if you are not scared of 1024 tabs initilizing and freezing them selves at the same time, then you can use any of this solutions. But i need a bullet proof one, so i decided, to give a *honor of finding a master tab* to the backend server.

Thanks everyone for help.

---

**After another research.**

There is a bullet proof answer under the post. It can work without a backend server.

Comment: Hopefully this link is still alive by the time someone reads this, but there's an updated version of the popular gist everyone likes to reference. https://github.com/fastmail/overture/blob/ca987c238fe774f07b699bc2ac514cdc476e058e/source/application/WindowController.js That's no longer pure, dependencyless js though, so you'll need to translate it somewhat for your own use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedWorker` can be used to solve the problem.

It will use dedicated blocking thread for all of communication between itself and other browser contexts (tabs/iframes). So it can be used to sync different things.

[MDN Article about SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem a while ago. I found this [windowcontroller.js](https://gist.github.com/neilj/4146038) from an app called Overture.

It correctly handles race conditions and timeouts.

I think it works out of the box but I modified it a bit to suit my needs.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that is not a bullet proof solution, if Math.random() will return 2 same numbers for 2 different tabs, if they will initilize in the same time, then it will call masterDidChange() two times. And browser will end up, again with conflict and 2 connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this communication with tabs with `storage` event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

In tab master:

```js
window.localStorage('foo', 'bar')
```

in all tabs:

```js
window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'foo') {
    // The foo localStorage key is updated on another tab,
    // so now I can update this tab
  }
})
```

Comment: The original answer suggested a library that used localStorage in the same manner as you suggest. And I already said that it's very trivial to run into a race condition. Open a debugger and try it yourself. Besides, it's no longer 2017, ServiceWorkers are ubiquitous.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the point of service workers with localStorage, can you explain it better? 

I debug it without any race condition, listening the storage event is the most reactive way to solve it. The only problem is that is not shared between browsers. 

In the case that you need to sync tabs between browsers then I suggest you different ways, for example the focus event of the tab and then sync the data with the server, or using WebSockets directly but probably you are going to find race conditions with WebSockets.